# Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Snapchat/Snapchat-441126967.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, image, flutter, storage

Please I keep getting this error, each time I try to pick an image on my flutter application. Taking a live picture from my camera on the app works well though, but when I try to access my storage the error keeps coming forth.

Note:
I use the image_picker package to pick both images and access the camera.

```
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Snapchat/Snapchat-441126967.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Everything was working well, of a sudden I started having this issue. I have done the following.

In my android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also I have the requestLegacyExternalStorage set to true.

In Pubsec.yaml

```
permission_handler: ^8.1.2
image_picker:
```

Flutter Version

```
Flutter 2.0.5 • channel stable
```

Block of code to pick image

```
 Future<void> _pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
    print(":: Pick Image executed :::");
    try {
      await Permission.storage.request();
      var status = await Permission.storage.status;
      print(":::: The Status of the permission is ::::");
      print(status);
      if (status.isGranted) {
        File selected =
        await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source, imageQuality: 30);
        final bytes = selected.readAsBytesSync();
        String _img64 = base64Encode(bytes);

        setState(() {
          _imageFile = selected;
          base64 = _img64;
        });
        uploadFile();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }

  }
```

The permission is granted as shown by the permission package but I still keep getting the error at the end of the day when I select an image from by device gallery.

Comment: An Android 11 device?

Comment: No Android 10 device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So eventually I found out that the problem was peculiar to only android 10 devices. The way forward was to update my image_picker package to the latest version which is at this moment 0.8.1+3.

And everything worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because of android storage permission. They solved the problem in the latest version. Please check out there read me file .

Starting with version 0.8.1 the Android implementation support to pick (multiple) images on Android 4.3 or higher.

No configuration required - the plugin should work out of the box.

It is no longer required to add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" as an attribute to the  tag in AndroidManifest.xml, as image_picker has been updated to make use of scoped storage.

Comment: Exactly, as stated in my answer above. Thanks for your reply.